# I remember meeting him yesterday

Tags: grammaticality

I remember meeting him yesterday. In this sentence, why is the gerund form of meet used instead of 'to meet'? Is there any rule for such use?

Comment: You could say "I remember that I met him yesterday."  I don't know how you'd say it with "to meet".

Comment: Note that you're remembering a "thing".  The gerund form can be used to convert a verb into a "thing".  Even though both use the "-ing" form of the verb, the gerund is different from the present continuous form of the verb:  "I am meeting with him now."

Comment: ...depends on the context: did you agree and then meet with him?...or did you meet with him a while ago and now are remembering that event?

Comment: "Remember" occurs with an infinitival complement when it has a past time meaning, as in _I remembered to meet him yesterday_ / _Did you remember to meet him yesterday?_, or with a future time meaning, as in _I must remember to meet him tomorrow_.

Comment: That's an interesting question.  I have two ideas to contribute but I don't feel sure enough about this to write an answer. (1)  The process of meeting is an inherently ongoing thing.  (2)  The alternative would be *remember to meet* -- and that has a special meaning, related to the concept of a reminder (or remembering, and not needing an external reminder).

Comment: @BillJ ...but...the OP was about "remember" in _the present tense_.

Answer (score 1):

> I ***remember*** *meeting* him yesterday.

The meaning is very dependent on your *exact* use of the present tense of ***remember***. Although many comments have been addressing the question of a past tense or future form usage, this does not seem to help you in this instance.

The sentence implies a memory that is being recalled *at the moment*. Moreover, what is being remembered is an event or action in the past.

...and as we all know, a gerund can function very nicely in this situation.

So, a plausible scenario might include something like...

> "Oh! Him! I remember meeting him just yesterday"

For me, a more natural usage would be in a situation like...

> I ***remember*** *locking* the door, but I don't think I remembered to set the alarm...

Notice I sneaked in another dependent clause with **remember** in the past tense + "to" + the infinitive. It has another meaning, as pointed out in the comments. The "remembering" was in the past, and so was the action of meeting him.

Please note that "I remember to meet yesterday" is just not good English, and I cannot think of where it might be used.

For more examples demonstrating the differences between the usages see:
https://www.crownacademyenglish.com/remember-infinitive-ing-form-gerund/......

or https://www.englishgrammar.org/ing-form-infinitive/

Comment: But the OP is specifically asking about _I remember to meet him yesterday_. And somehow your answer doesn't address that sentence.

Comment: @listeneva   ...erm..the Q was about _remember meeting him yesterday_...check it out.  i.e. "Why is the gerund form used..."

Comment: But the OP wonders why the gerund form **instead of 'to meet'**. So I would think it would be helpful if you addressed _I remember to meet him yesterday_ as well.

Comment: @listeneva Perhaps on ELL.SE they might have that type of patience; however, here we prefer to address specific points. The links I provided should serve to satisfy the most inquisitive of _learners_.

Comment: Are you saying that it's impossible to say _I remember to meet him tomorrow_?

Comment: @listeneva OK...I addressed the issue of "remember to meet yesterday". ie has no usage in good English